# Open link in new tab when ctrl + click it in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with that, I don't found the solution. How I can ctrl + click on a link for open in new tab ?

```
 function handleClick(documentID) {
    // if ctrl + click
    window.open(`/document/${documentID}`, "_blank")
    // else
    // navigate("/document/" + documentID)
  }

 <ListItem onClick={() => handleClick(document.id)}>
```

i have comment the code for understand well

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You want to open every time the link in a new tab or only when the user use ctrl+click?

Comment: Isn't ctrl+click to new window baked into browsers? FE code typically does not have to handle that explicitly.

Comment: @Giacomo i want to when i just click on my document, he's open on the same page where the link is and when i press ctrl + click on the link i want to open him in a new tab

Comment: @lux oh, i dont know

Comment: Instead of the function `handleClick` you can use the `react-router` library and create the link with the  `<Link/>` component. In this way it works like a normal `<a>` link.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass event to function instead just ID. This way you can check for Ctrl:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  const documentID = event.id;

  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    window.open(`/document/${documentID}`, "_blank")
  } else {
    navigate("/document/" + documentID)
  }
}

<ListItem onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)}>
```

You can also extend your function for mouse wheel click:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const documentID = event.id;

  if (event.ctrlKey || event.button === 1) {
    window.open(`/document/${documentID}`, "_blank")
  } else if (event.type === 'click') {
    navigate("/document/" + documentID)
  }
}

<ListItem onClick={(event) => handleClick(event)} onMouseDown={(event) => handleClick(event)}>
```

Use anchor `<a>` (or react `<Link>` component) tag if you can, this is prefered way.

Comment: Mouse wheel might not work, `onAuxClick` should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a link, please use an actual `a` element with a href.
This is better for accessibility and you get the CTRL + click feature for free.